# Get bend arrow right (dangling head, not curved)

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is wrong with the code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

% \usetikzlibrary{⟨list of libraries separated by commas⟩}
\usetikzlibrary[trees,shapes,arrows]
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
  arrow1/.style={<->, latex-latex, line width=1mm, draw},
  arrow2/.style={->, >=latex, draw}
}

    \coordinate (sw) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (ne) at (6,6);
    \begin{scope}
        % \clip  (sw) rectangle (ne); % clip some region
%       \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{../Bilder/Explanations/early-abandoning.png}};
    %     [trim=left bottom right top, clip]
%       \draw (3,2) -- ++(70:3cm) -- ++(-50:1cm) -- ++(20:1cm) -- ++(0:1cm);
%       \draw (3,2) -- ++(70:3cm) -- ++(-50:1cm) -- ++(20:1cm) -- ++(0:1cm);
        \draw[line width=1mm] (20,19)  -- ++(60:3cm) -- ++(40:2cm) -- ++(20:1cm) -- ++(0:1cm);
        \draw[line width=1mm] (16,24)  -- ++(-30:3cm) -- ++(10:2cm);
        \draw[arrow1] (20.7,22.6) -- ++(-50:1.1cm);
        \path[arrow2] (20.9,22.9) edge[top bend] ++(45:2cm); % 
%       \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
%           \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
%           \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
%           \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
%       \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I just cannot get rid of the dangling arrow head and get the arrow line to be curved:

[image]

I am using a rather old version of tikz, since I am on Kubuntu 14.4 - not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't know the key `top bend`. If you replace it by `bend left`, say, there is no error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something without error, without dangling arrow and with a bent line.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary[trees,shapes,arrows]
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
  arrow1/.style={<->, latex-latex, line width=1mm, draw},
  arrow2/.style={->, >=latex, draw}
}

    \coordinate (sw) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (ne) at (6,6);
    \begin{scope}
        \draw[line width=1mm] (20,19)  -- ++(60:3cm) -- ++(40:2cm) -- ++(20:1cm) -- ++(0:1cm);
        \draw[line width=1mm] (16,24)  -- ++(-30:3cm) -- ++(10:2cm);
        \draw[arrow1] (20.7,22.6) -- ++(-50:1.1cm);
        \path[arrow2] (20.9,22.9) to[bend left=15] ++(45:2cm); % 
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What was the problem? I see the difference in code, but can you explain the technicalities?

Comment: @Make42 As I mentioned in my comment, AFAIK there is no `top bend` directive in the standard libraries. And I replaced the `edge` by `to` such that there is really a path.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I got  the code from another stackexchange answer, maybe that was wrong.